# OSX script to Check if ffmpeg process has stopped

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I have a Automator Workflow that uses Videobox to convert flash videos for multiple devices but cannot tell when it finish a conversion,I know that it uses ffmpeg for its conversion as I can see it in Activity Monitor,I need a script check that the ffmpeg process is running or not .Applescript SystemEvents cannot see this ffmpeg process is there another way to do this in applescript?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried soething like this?

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat while exists process "PROCESS_NAME"
    end repeat
end tell
```

If that does not work, you can use a different approach.

You can add an AppleScript task that checks the size of the converted file:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"
        set first_size to ""
        set second_size to " "

        repeat until first_size is equal to second_size
            set first_size to size of (info for input) as integer
            delay 2
            set second_size to size of (info for input) as integer
        end repeat
    end tell
end run
```

This task will end when the size of passed input file stops changing.